# Segmentation fault while using vfprintf()

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault

The following program is hitting a segmentation fault, and I cannot figure out what the problem is.

```
  1 #include<stdio.h>
  2 #include<stdarg.h>
  3 void writeformat(FILE*,char*, ...);
  4 int main()
  5 {
  6   FILE *fp;
  7   fp=fopen("file1.txt","w");
  8   writeformat(fp,"/modules.php?name=Top&querylang=%20WHERE%201=2%20ALL%20SELECT%201,pwd,1,1%20FROM%20nuke_authors/*");
  9   fclose(fp);
 10   return(0);
 11 }
 12 
 13 void writeformat(FILE *stream,char *format, ...)
 14 {
 15   va_list args;
 16   va_start(args,format);
 17   vfprintf(stream,format,args);
 18   va_end(args);
 19 }
```

I tried in gdb, and it tells me the problem is in `vfprintf()`:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /ws/anaganes-sjc/junk 
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x2aaaaaaab000

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000003c44c7fb30 in wcslen () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000003c44c7fb30 in wcslen () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000003c44c80b27 in wcsrtombs () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000003c44c464b2 in vfprintf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x0000000000400649 in writeformat (stream=0x601010, format=0x400758 "/modules.php?name=Top&querylang=%20WHERE%201=2%20ALL%20SELECT%201,pwd,1,1%20FROM%20nuke_authors/*") at junk.c:20
#4  0x0000000000400556 in main () at junk.c:9
```

Can you please help me find the problem?

Comment: [in rhetorical mode] did you check for the success of `fopen()`?

Comment: You might like to use `writeformat(fp, "%s", "/modules.php?name=.....`.

Answer (score 8):

Your format string contains escaped space characters. The escape is done with percent signs, HTML style:

```
"querylang=%20WHERE%201=2%20ALL%20SELECT%201..."
```

These percent signs have a meaning in `printf` style format strings. You must either render the spaces verbatim:

```
"querylang= WHERE 1=2 ALL SELECT 1..."
```

or use `printf`'s  own escape for printing percent signs, namely `%%`:

```
"querylang=%%20WHERE%%201=2%%20ALL%%20SELECT%%201..."
```

or, as alk points out in a comment, use the string format and print your string as argument:

```
writeformat(fp, "%s", "/modules.php?name=");
```

which is the best way to print strings that have or could have formatting specifiers verbatim.

You get a segmentation violation, because each format specified with `%` except `%%` expects an additional argument. For example `%20A` withh print a binary representation of a float of width 20. It therefore expects a double argument, but you haven't specified any arguments, so `vprintf` tries to acess memory beyond the bound of the variable argument list.

Many compilers can warn you about format mismatches for the well-known `printf` functions. Some compilers allow you to label arguments of your own functions as `printf` like format strings. Microsoft's SAL or gcc-style attributes will let you do that.

Comment: Is that... a _forward_ tick?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I guess you mean the garbled layout? It was a forward tick, which on my keyboard is on the same key as the back tick and holding down the shift key at the same time with the other hand is hard. I've fixed the formatting, thanks.

Comment: I wasn't complaining, just interested :)

Answer (score 2):

`vfprintf` thinks you're passing some varargs with data in them, because your format string contains `%`.

It looks like you meant for those `%` to be printed verbatim, so you must escape them as `%%`:

```
"/modules.php?name=Top&querylang="
"%%20WHERE%%201=2%%20ALL%%20SELECT%%201,pwd,1,1%%20FROM%%20nuke_authors/*"
```

Incidentally, that `/*` probably shouldn't be there and the query itself seems odd. Either this is really weird code, or you're up to no good.

Answer (score 1):

When passing strings to [vfprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf), the `%` character is interpreted as the introduction to a conversion specification. In order to keep `%` verbatim, you'll have to escape it. This is done by replacing each `%` with the conversion specification `%%`.

Answer (score 0):

GCC would catch the format string error *at compile time* if you marked `writeformat` as taking a `printf`-style format string:

```
void writeformat(FILE *stream, char *format, ...)
     __attribute__((format (printf, 2, 3)));
```

In passing, I question the `void` return type - do you really mean to ignore the return value of `vprintf`?